# Geometric Sequence Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Problem:

> (a) Determine all nonnegative integers $r$ such that it is possible for an infinite arithmetic sequence to contain exactly $r$ terms that are integers. Prove your answer.
>
> (b) Determine all nonnegative integers $r$ such that it is possible for an infinite geometric sequence to contain exactly $r$ terms that are integers. Prove your answer.

My Solution for $a)$:

> **$a)$** First, we can analyze the case when $r \geq 2$. In this case, there will be at least $2$ terms in the arithmetic sequence which are integers; $a+md$ and $a+nd$. WLOG, $m>n$. These terms are both integers, so $(m-n)d$ is also an integer. Adding $(m - n)d$ to $a + md$ gives $a + (2m - n)d$, which is also a member of the arithmetic sequence and an integer, so this process can continue, giving the arithmetic sequence an infinite number of terms. Therefore, $r$ can only be $r=1$.

I am currently stuck on $b)$, but I know that we could do a similar approach, but how would I do it?

Comment: Can a geometric series be extended in both directions?

Comment: I guess so... Is this what I need to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. Consider two integers in a geometric progression separated by some powers of the ratio $a$. Then it should be possible to extend the series in one direction infinitely to yield an infinite number of integers. Thus $r$ can only be one, which is achieved by (e.g.) a base value of 1 and a multiplier of $\pi$.

Comment: 8,4,2,1,1/2,1/4,...

Comment: You have asked several questions here and gotten some nice answers, but I don't see where you have ever clicked to check mark to Accept an answer. Why is that?

Comment: @BruceET what does the check mark do?

Comment: (1) Lets us know that you have a useful answer, (2) Removes the Question from the list of questions without useful answers. (3) Gives person who answered a few 'reputation points'. // Please take the 'tour' of the site so you will know how to post best questions and the mechanics of how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

For part (b):

Take a positive integer $m$.

Construct a GP with first term $m^{r-1}$ and common ratio $\frac 1m$. The GP is

$$\overbrace{ m^{r-1}, m^{r-2},m^{r-3},\cdots\cdots,m^2, m^1, 1}^{r \text{  integer terms}}, \overbrace{\frac 1m, \frac 1{m^2},\cdots\cdots\cdots}^{\text{non-integer terms}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{a+nt\}$ (where the sequence starts at $n=0$). $r=0$ is achieved when $a,t$ are irrational. $r=1$ is achieved when $a$ is an integer and $t$ is irrational. $r\geq 2$ is impossible because given two integers $n, m$ in the sequence (WLOG $n<m$) , $m+(m-n)$ is in the sequence.

Consider $\{at^n\}$ (where the sequence starts at $n=0$). $r=0$ is achieved when $a$ is irrational and $t$ is an integer. $r=1$ is achieved when $a$ is an integer and $t$ is irrational. $r\ge 2$ is impossible because given integers $n$, $nt^k$ in the sequence $t^k$ is an integer and $nt^{2k}$ is an integer.

What about the arithmetic and geometric sequences gives them this property? Is there a more general class of sequences with this property? What types of sequences have infinitely many $r$ values?

Comment: Please use MathJax in the future. I have corrected this post for you.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, for **(b)** any nonnegative integer $r$ works. If you want exactly $r$ terms to be integers, take $2^{r-1}, 2^{r-2}, 2^{r-3},..., 2^2, 2, 1, \frac{1}{2}, ...$

example: $r=3$

$\text{ratio}=\frac{1}{3}$

we get $2^{3-1}, 2^{3-2}, 2^{3-3}$, and those are all the integer terms.

I'm only an 8th grader so there may be a flaw in my thinking, if so please correct me!

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math thank you.